# angular js referencing a controller from multiple modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple controller in a module, which opens a modal tpl and displays a text (link)
The code:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, direct_link) {

    $scope.direct_link = direct_link;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
```

The calling code:

```
$scope.open_direct_link = function(recipe_id) {
            $scope.direct_link = "blababla";
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'mymodule/directLink.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    direct_link: function () {
                        return $scope.direct_link;
                    }
                }

            });
        };
```

Now I want to refactor the code to be able to use the exact controller in a different module.
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: It's better off to set up a directive

Comment: I was thinking in that direction - can a directive render a modal view? can you provide me a point to start from?

Comment: http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/